# Not possible to compile. Headers files.Enclosed own objects definition

Tags: c++, class, opencv, g++, libraries

Here I am with a similar question as the last time, and for which I could not find any answer.

Note that I consider important: Normally I compile my programs in opencv with the next command:

```
g++ -o def program.cpp `pkg-config --cflags opencv` `pkg-config --libs opencv`
```

This line will create an executable whose name will be def and that I will be able to use.

I am working in a project, and as it was getting bigger, I had to define some objects, just to make everything easier and possible to handle. I create one object from the files: homogra.cpp and homogra.h the comand I used for it was:

```
g++ -c  homogra.cpp `pkg-config --cflags opencv` `pkg-config --libs opencv`
```

Then, I wrote in my program.cpp the line     #include "homogra.h"

And I compile like:

```
 g++ -o def program.cpp homogra.o `pkg-config --cflags opencv` `pkg-config --libs opencv`
```

Until now everything is working fine.

Then I create a second object(with the same compilation line as for homogra, but this time with segmentator.cpp and segmentator.h), i wrote the line #include "segmentator.h",(in program.cpp) and I compile like:

```
g++ -o def program.cpp .o segmentator.o `pkg-config --cflags opencv` `pkg-config --libs opencv`
```

Now it is not working, and it is not recognising segmentator. I checked already if segmentator was working and everything works fine if homogra is the only include in the program.cpp.

I notice something strange. If I change the lines and I write before,in the #include lines,  #include "segmentator.h" and then #include "homogra.h", then the compiler, with the same line for compiling :

```
 g++ -o def program.cpp homogra.o segmentator.o `pkg-config --cflags opencv` `pkg-config --libs opencv`
```

is only recognising this time segmentator and not homogra. It is maybe a little difficult to understand, I tried to explained it as better as possible.

Any help!?

Many thanks in advance.

Here is homogra.h:

```
using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

#ifndef _NAMES_H  
#define _NAMES_H   
class homogra {
public:

    Mat matCalculation( Mat img, Mat img2);
    void printMatrix(Mat matrix);

};
#endif
```

In homogra.cpp I have all the tipical includes and homogra.h:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include "opencv2/features2d/features2d.hpp"
#include "opencv2/calib3d/calib3d.hpp"
#include "homogra.h"
```

And then the functions explained.

Object 2 is segmentator.h

```
 using namespace cv;
 using namespace std;

#ifndef _NAMES_H  
#define _NAMES_H   
 class segmentator {
public:

    void search(Mat img,vector<std::vector<cv::Point> >& contours);

     void similar(vector<std::vector<cv::Point> >& contours,vector<std::vector<cv::Point> >& contours2,vector<int>& idx);

    vector<Mat> separate(Mat img,Mat img2,vector<std::vector<cv::Point> >&   contours,vector<std::vector<cv::Point> >& contours2,vector<int> idx);
};

#endif
```

And in segmentator.cpp I have again all the same includes, except homogra.h and instead of this one I have segmentator.h.

Program.cpp is image_reg.cpp:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include "opencv2/features2d/features2d.hpp"
#include "opencv2/calib3d/calib3d.hpp"
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>

#include "homogra.h"
#include "segmentator.h" 
 using namespace cv;
 using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char ** argv )
{ //Here is the code where I try to invoque two instances of homogra and segmentator.
}
```

If I let homogra.h as the first to be read in the includes list of image_reg.cpp then only homogra.h is recognised, if I let at the first position segmentator, then only segmentator.h instances would be created and homogra. h would not be recognised.

Thanks

Comment: How do you create object2? You omitted that invocation.

Comment: "Now it is not working, and it is not recognising object2." - what error message do you get?

Comment: Object2 was created the same way as object 1 with the line:g++ -c  object2.cpp `pkg-config --cflags opencv` `pkg-config --libs opencv`

Comment: @wolfgang I am getting a message as the typical binding error: object2 was not declared on this scope.

Comment: Does `object2.cpp` include `object2.h`?

Comment: @juanchopanza Yes As well, both can work separatedly. I mean, i checked that both of them work.

Comment: OK, the error message belongs in the question. BTW, it's a compiler error, not a linker error, and I've never heard of a "binding error".

Comment: Please post at least the contents of Object2.h, preferably also program.cpp.

Comment: Suggest you revise your question so that you only use the names 'segmentator' and 'homogra', rather thasn object1 and object2. It's a confusing mess at present.

Comment: ok, I am gonna correct it, thanks to everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your include header guards are  wrong. They should be unique, using the name of the source file, rather than just `_NAMES_H`.

So in homogra.h you should have this:

```
#ifndef HOMOGRA_H  
#define HOMOGRA_H   
...
#endif
```

...and in segmentator.h, you should have this

```
#ifndef SEGMENTATOR_H  
#define SEGMENTATOR_H   
...
#endif
```

Also, it's [really bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5849457/using-namespace-in-c-headers) to have a `using namespace xxx;` in a header file. You make it very difficult for your headers to coexist with others.

As Jonathan Wakely points out, beginning symbols with underscores is not a great idea, either.

Comment: Thanks, I am gonna have a read about the namespaces topics. Thanks.

Comment: @Ivánovick it isn't to do with namespaces, but with the preprocessor `#ifndef` and `#define` directives. Look up "include guards".

Comment: It's also **really** bad practice (as in forbidden) to use names that start with an underscore followed by a capital letter, only the implementation (i.e. the compiler and standard library and OS) are allowed to use such names. Just call them e.g. `HOMOGRA_H` and `SEGMENTATOR_H` instead.

Comment: @JonathanWakely: What makes you so certain he isn't writing code for an OS, compiler, or standard library? ;-) Point taken, though, and answer revised.